# Change "primary" branch of a git commit?

Tags: git, branch, commit

On GitHub my network graph looks like this

```
---o---o---X--------------o---o master
            \
             Y-----Z test
              \
               o---o------o----------o devel
```

Whereas in "spirit" it should look more like this.

```
---o---o---X--------------o---o master
            \
             Y----o-----o-----o-----------o devel
              \
               Z test
```

The `test` branch was just a test of a new feature, from the first graph it makes it look like `devel` is a branch from `test`

Comment: If the test branch was not displayed in the graph they would look exactly the same?  They look like the same tree structure, just a different picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Y` is "owned" by both `test` and `devel` branches. To fix this I arranged so that it is only "owned" by `devel` branch.

## Part 1 (using gitk)

- Create patch from `X` to `Z`
- Create new branch `temp` from `X`

## Part 2 (using git)

- Apply patch to `temp` branch
- Commit

## Part 3 (back to gitk)

- Hard reset `test` to `temp`
- Delete `temp` branch

[gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to name `master~2`, the point of divergence, "X" for clarity.

You can rebase the `test` branch to lie atop X, and then rebase `devel` to originate on `test`.

There is no way to do the swap without changing all the hashes of commits on both `devel` and `master`, since each commit includes a reference to its parents, and what you want to do changes the parents of both `test` and `devel~4`. So, only history-rewriting commands like `rebase` or a movement of the ref names will accomplish your goal.